# How to find "nearest" value in a large list in Erlang

Tags: search, erlang, binary-search

Suppose I have a large collection of integers (say 50,000,000 of them).

I would like to write a function that returns me the largest integer in the collection that doesn't exceed a value passed as a parameter to the function. E.g. if the values were:

```
 Values = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

then `find(Values, 25)` should return 20.

The function will be called many times a second and the collection is large. Assuming that the performance of a brute-force search is too slow, what would be an efficient way to do it? The integers would rarely change, so they can be stored in a data structure that would give the fastest access.

I've looked at gb_trees but I don't think you can obtain the "insertion point" and then get the previous entry.

I realise I could do this from scratch by building my own tree structure, or binary chopping a sorted array, but is there some built-in way to do it that I've overlooked?

Comment: If the values are *not* sorted, this would be more clear if the sample data is *not* sorted. (The sorted approach is definitely the simplest and has good time complexity, especially when amortized over many calls.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another code sample that uses ets. I believe a lookup would be made in about constant time:

```
1> ets:new(tab,[named_table, ordered_set, public]).
2> lists:foreach(fun(N) -> ets:insert(tab,{N,[]}) end, lists:seq(1,50000000)).
3> timer:tc(fun() -> ets:prev(tab, 500000) end).
{21,499999}
4> timer:tc(fun() -> ets:prev(tab, 41230000) end).
{26,41229999}
```

The code surrounding would be a bit more than this of course but it is rather neat

Comment: That's interesting. I'd assumed ets:prev/2 required the key to be an existing key in the set. I'll try it out - thanks!

Comment: So simple! As Paul says, I had in mind that the key must exist. You should add a small value to get the right answer ets:prev(tab, 500000.1)  :o)

Comment: @PaulCager No the key does not need to exist **IFF** the table is of type *ordered_set*. For *set* and *bag* the key must exist.

Answer (score 4):

To find nearest value in large unsorted list I'd suggest you to use **divide and conquer** strategy - and **process different parts of list in parallel**. But enough **small parts of list may be processed sequentially**.

Here is code for you:

```
-module( finder ).
-export( [ nearest/2 ] ).

-define( THRESHOLD, 1000 ).

%%
%% sequential finding of nearest value
%%
%% if nearest value doesn't exists - return null
%%
nearest( Val, List ) when length(List) =< ?THRESHOLD ->
        lists:foldl(
                fun
                ( X, null ) when X < Val ->
                        X;
                ( _X, null ) ->
                        null;
                ( X, Nearest ) when X < Val, X > Nearest ->
                        X;
                ( _X, Nearest ) ->
                        Nearest
                end,
                null,
                List );
%%
%% split large lists and process each part in parallel
%%
nearest( Val, List ) ->
        { Left, Right } = lists:split( length(List) div 2, List ),
        Ref1 = spawn_nearest( Val, Left ),
        Ref2 = spawn_nearest( Val, Right ),
        Nearest1 = receive_nearest( Ref1 ),
        Nearest2 = receive_nearest( Ref2 ),
        %%
        %% compare nearest values from each part
        %%
        case { Nearest1, Nearest2 } of
                { null, null } ->
                        null;
                { null, Nearest2 } ->
                        Nearest2;
                { Nearest1, null } ->
                        Nearest1;
                { Nearest1, Nearest2 } when Nearest2 > Nearest1 ->
                        Nearest2;
                { Nearest1, Nearest2 } when Nearest2 =< Nearest1 ->
                        Nearest1
        end.

spawn_nearest( Val, List ) ->
        Ref = make_ref(),
        SelfPid = self(),
        spawn(
                fun() ->
                        SelfPid ! { Ref, nearest( Val, List ) }
                end ),
        Ref.

receive_nearest( Ref ) ->
        receive
                { Ref, Nearest } -> Nearest
        end.
```

[image]

Testing in shell:

```
1> c(finder).
{ok,finder}
2> 
2> List = [ random:uniform(1000) || _X <- lists:seq(1,100000) ].
[444,724,946,502,312,598,916,667,478,597,143,210,698,160,
 559,215,458,422,6,563,476,401,310,59,579,990,331,184,203|...]
3> 
3> finder:nearest( 500, List ).
499
4>
4> finder:nearest( -100, lists:seq(1,100000) ).
null
5> 
5> finder:nearest( 40000, lists:seq(1,100000) ).
39999
6> 
6> finder:nearest( 4000000, lists:seq(1,100000) ).
100000
```

**Performance:** (single node)

```
7> 
7> timer:tc( finder, nearest, [ 40000, lists:seq(1,10000) ] ). 
{3434,10000}
8> 
8> timer:tc( finder, nearest, [ 40000, lists:seq(1,100000) ] ).
{21736,39999}
9>
9> timer:tc( finder, nearest, [ 40000, lists:seq(1,1000000) ] ).
{314399,39999}
```

Versus plain iterating:

```
1> 
1> timer:tc( lists, foldl, [ fun(_X, Acc) -> Acc end, null, lists:seq(1,10000) ] ).
{14994,null}
2> 
2> timer:tc( lists, foldl, [ fun(_X, Acc) -> Acc end, null, lists:seq(1,100000) ] ).
{141951,null}
3>
3> timer:tc( lists, foldl, [ fun(_X, Acc) -> Acc end, null, lists:seq(1,1000000) ] ).
{1374426,null}
```

So, yo may see, that on list with **1000000** elements, function `finder:nearest` is **faster** than plain iterating through list with `lists:foldl`.

You may find optimal value of `THRESHOLD` in your case.

**Also you may improve performance, if spawn processes on different nodes.**

Answer (score 1):

So if the input isn't sorted, you can get a linear version by doing:

```
closest(Target, [Hd | Tl ]) ->
        closest(Target, Tl, Hd).

closest(_Target, [], Best) -> Best;
closest(Target, [ Target | _ ], _) -> Target;
closest(Target, [ N | Rest ], Best) ->
    CurEps = erlang:abs(Target - Best),
    NewEps = erlang:abs(Target -  N),
    if NewEps < CurEps ->
            closest(Target, Rest, N);
       true ->
            closest(Target, Rest, Best)
    end.
```

You should be able to do better if the input is sorted.

I invented my own metric for 'closest' here as I allow the closest value to be higher than the target value - you could change it to be 'closest but not greater than' if you liked.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you have a huge collection of data that does not change often, you shoud think about organize it.
I have wrote a simple one based on ordered list, including insertion an deletion functions. It gives good results for both inserting and searching.

```
-module(finder).

-export([test/1,find/2,insert/2,remove/2,new/0]).

-compile(export_all).

new() -> [].

insert(V,L) -> 
    {R,P} = locate(V,L,undefined,-1),
    insert(V,R,P,L).

find(V,L) -> 
    locate(V,L,undefined,-1).

remove(V,L) ->  
    {R,P} = locate(V,L,undefined,-1),
    remove(V,R,P,L).

test(Max) -> 
    {A,B,C} = erlang:now(),
    random:seed(A,B,C),
    L = lists:seq(0,100*Max,100),
    S = random:uniform(100000000),
    I = random:uniform(100000000),
    io:format("start insert at ~p~n",[erlang:now()]),
    L1 = insert(I,L),
    io:format("start find at ~p~n",[erlang:now()]),
    R = find(S,L1),
    io:format("end at ~p~n result is ~p~n",[erlang:now(),R]).

remove(_,_,-1,L) -> L;
remove(V,V,P,L) ->
    {L1,[V|L2]} = lists:split(P,L),
    L1 ++ L2;
remove(_,_,_,L) ->L.

insert(V,V,_,L) -> L;
insert(V,_,-1,L) -> [V|L];
insert(V,_,P,L) ->
    {L1,L2} = lists:split(P+1,L),
    L1 ++ [V] ++ L2.

locate(_,[],R,P) -> {R,P};
locate (V,L,R,P) -> 
    %% io:format("locate, value = ~p, liste = ~p, current result = ~p, current pos = ~p~n",[V,L,R,P]),
    {L1,[M|L2]} = lists:split(Le1 = (length(L) div 2), L),
    locate(V,R,P,Le1+1,L1,M,L2).

locate(V,_,P,Le,_,V,_) -> {V,P+Le};
locate(V,_,P,Le,_,M,L2) when V > M -> locate(V,L2,M,P+Le);
locate(V,R,P,_,L1,_,_) -> locate(V,L1,R,P).
```

which give the following results

> (exec@WXFRB1824L)6> finder:test(10000000).
>
> start insert at {1347,28177,618000}
>
> start find at {1347,28178,322000}
>
> end at {1347,28178,728000}
>
> result is {72983500,729836}

that is 704ms to insert a new value in a list of 10 000 000 elements and 406ms to find the nearest value int the same list.

Comment: However, on my laptop, i am stuck when I try to generate a 50 000 000 integers list (eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 298930300 bytes of memory). so it it is not the right storage to use :o(.

Comment: Thanks. That was the kind of thing I was thinking of - how to structure the data for easy look up. I was thinking along the lines of  fixed arrays and binary searches.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to have a more accurate information about the performance of the algorithm  I proposed above, an reading the very interesting solution of Stemm, I decide to use the tc:timer/3 function. Big deception :o). On my laptop, I got a very bad accuracy of the time. So I decided to left my corei5 (2 cores * 2 threads) + 2Gb DDR3 + windows XP 32bit to use my home PC: Phantom (6 cores) + 8Gb + Linux 64bit.

Now tc:timer works as expected, I am able to manipulate lists of 100 000 000 integers. I was able to see that I was loosing a lot of time calling at each step the length function, so I re-factored the code a little to avoid it:

```
-module(finder).

-export([test/2,find/2,insert/2,remove/2,new/0]).

%% interface

new() -> {0,[]}.

insert(V,{S,L}) -> 
    {R,P} = locate(V,L,S,undefined,-1),
    insert(V,R,P,L,S).

find(V,{S,L}) -> 
    locate(V,L,S,undefined,-1).

remove(V,{S,L}) ->  
    {R,P} = locate(V,L,S,undefined,-1),
    remove(V,R,P,L,S).

remove(_,_,-1,L,S) -> {S,L};
remove(V,V,P,L,S) ->
    {L1,[V|L2]} = lists:split(P,L),
    {S-1,L1 ++ L2};
remove(_,_,_,L,S) ->{S,L}.

%% local

insert(V,V,_,L,S) -> {S,L};
insert(V,_,-1,L,S) -> {S+1,[V|L]};
insert(V,_,P,L,S) ->
    {L1,L2} = lists:split(P+1,L),
    {S+1,L1 ++ [V] ++ L2}.

locate(_,[],_,R,P) -> {R,P};
locate (V,L,S,R,P) -> 
    S1 = S div 2,
    S2 = S - S1 -1,
    {L1,[M|L2]} = lists:split(S1, L),
    locate(V,R,P,S1+1,L1,S1,M,L2,S2).

locate(V,_,P,Le,_,_,V,_,_) -> {V,P+Le};
locate(V,_,P,Le,_,_,M,L2,S2) when V > M -> locate(V,L2,S2,M,P+Le);
locate(V,R,P,_,L1,S1,_,_,_) -> locate(V,L1,S1,R,P).

%% test

test(Max,Iter) -> 
    {A,B,C} = erlang:now(),
    random:seed(A,B,C),
    L = {Max+1,lists:seq(0,100*Max,100)},
    Ins = test_insert(L,Iter,[]),
    io:format("insert:~n~s~n",[stat(Ins,Iter)]),
    Fin = test_find(L,Iter,[]),
    io:format("find:~n ~s~n",[stat(Fin,Iter)]).

test_insert(_L,0,Res) -> Res;
test_insert(L,I,Res) ->
    V = random:uniform(1000000000),
    {T,_} = timer:tc(finder,insert,[V,L]),
    test_insert(L,I-1,[T|Res]).

test_find(_L,0,Res) -> Res;
test_find(L,I,Res) ->
    V = random:uniform(1000000000),
    {T,_} = timer:tc(finder,find,[V,L]),
    test_find(L,I-1,[T|Res]).

stat(L,N) ->
    Aver = lists:sum(L)/N,
    {Min,Max,Var} = lists:foldl(fun (X,{Mi,Ma,Va}) -> {min(X,Mi),max(X,Ma),Va+(X-Aver)*(X-Aver)} end, {999999999999999999999999999,0,0}, L),
    Sig = math:sqrt(Var/N),
    io_lib:format("   average: ~p,~n   minimum: ~p,~n   maximum: ~p,~n   sigma   : ~p.~n",[Aver,Min,Max,Sig]).
```

Here are some results.

> 1> finder:test(1000,10).
>        insert:
>
> average: 266.7,
>
> minimum: 216,
>
> maximum: 324,
>
> sigma   : 36.98121144581393.
>
> find:
>
> ```
> average: 136.1,
> ```
>
> minimum: 105,
>
> maximum: 162,
>
> sigma   : 15.378231367748375.
>
> ok
>
> 2> finder:test(100000,10).
>
> insert:
>
> average: 10096.5,
>
> minimum: 9541,
>
> maximum: 12222,
>
> sigma   : 762.5642595873478.
>
> find:
>
> ```
> average: 5077.4,
> ```
>
> minimum: 4666,
>
> maximum: 6937,
>
> sigma   : 627.126494417195.
>
> ok
>
> 3> finder:test(1000000,10).
>
> insert:
>
> average: 109871.1,
>
> minimum: 94747,
>
> maximum: 139916,
>
> sigma   : 13852.211285206417.
>
> find:
>       average: 40428.0,
>
> minimum: 31297,
>
> maximum: 56965,
>
> sigma   : 7797.425562325042.
>
> ok
>
> 4> finder:test(100000000,10).
>
> insert:
>
> average: 8067547.8,
>
> minimum: 6265625,
>
> maximum: 16590349,
>
> sigma   : 3199868.809140206.
>
> find:
>
> ```
> average: 8484876.4,
> ```
>
> minimum: 5158504,
>
> maximum: 15950944,
>
> sigma   : 4044848.707872872.
>
> ok

On the 100 000 000 list, it is slow, and the multi process solution cannot help on this dichotomy algorithm... It is a weak point of this solution, but if you have several processes in parallel requesting to find a nearest value, it will be able to use the multicore anyway.

Pascal.